# Web scraping with Xpath, grabbing img

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to scrape some img from page. But couldn't grab those. My path is true(i think) but Xpath returns 0. Any idea what is wrong with my path?

```
function pageContent($url)
{

    $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    });

    $parser = new \DOMDocument();
    $parser->loadHTML($html);
    return $parser;

}

$url = 'https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/osaka';

@$parser = pageContent($url);

$resimler = [];
$rota = new \DOMXPath($parser);
$images = $rota->query("//section//div[@class='p-articlelist-content-left']//div[@class='p-articlelist-content-img']//img");


foreach ($images as $image) {
    $resimler[] = $image->getAttribute("src");
}

var_dump($resimler);
```

Comment: What happens if you do `var_dump( $images )` or `dd( $images )` above your foreach-loop? 

If that doesn't get you anything, then perhaps try to simplify your expression. Eg.: `$rota->query("//section")` - to see if that gives you something useful.

Comment: it gives me nothing. @Zeth

Comment: Where do you see a `div` with class `p-articlelist-content-img` in the HTML source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking for a `div[@class='p-articlelist-content-img']` instead of a `ul`.

In addition to that, you should not be hiding error messages with the `@` operator, instead use the [`libxml_use_internal_errors()` function](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) as it was intended.

Finally, the `//` search in XPath is expensive, so avoid it where possible, and you can get the attribute value directly from the query (I don't know if this is any more efficient though.)

```
function pageContent(String $url) : \DOMDocument
{
    $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    });
    $parser = new \DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $parser->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    return $parser;
}

$url    = "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/osaka";
$parser = pageContent($url);
$rota   = new \DOMXPath($parser);
$images = $rota->query("//ul[@class='p-articlelist-content-img']/li/img/@src");

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $resimler[] = $image->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($resimler);
```